# htacces redirect if e-tag or last-modified in request header

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, last-modified, etag

I've tried searching around for an answer but can't find any tutorials or docs I can make sense of so I'm not even sure if it's possible, but;

I would like to redirect/rewrite a URL if the last modified date or etag is in the request header. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond # Only if the request uri is 'images/1px.gif'
RewriteCond # And if an etag or last modified date is in the req. header
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /304-this.php [L]
```

Note even sure if this is possible, if it's not what would you suggest be a better option.

Just to be clear, I also only want this redirect to fire if the request is for `images/1px.gif` and there is an etag or a last modified date.

My theory is if the image is already in the browsers cache it will be sent with a etag or last modified date and in which case, I want PHP to handle the 304 response.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%{HTTP:...}` in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for testing any header

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:etag} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:last-modified} .
RewriteRule images/1px.gif$ /304-this.php [L]
```